# Audits/Monitoring you have set up at work

Tags: sql, sql-server, monitoring, audit, auditing

I want to set up some auditing and monitoring jobs on my production servers, but my knowledge of SQL Server is limited, so I wanted to reach out and ask you what are the things that you audit and things that you monitor at your own job.  Thanks.

Comment: It is a big topic for discussion. Start by researching this topic first and then ask targeted questions.

Comment: With all due respect I disagree.  I asked people to list what they are auditing/monitoring.  I didn't ask them what is auditing/monitoring, why do it, how to do it, etc.

Comment: This site is not a discussion forum (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) but a Q&A. I was suggesting that you ask a targeted question along the lines of: "My circumstance is Y. I will audit Z. Not sure about X? Anything else you would recommend?"

Comment: Alex, here's the question:

Q:  What auditing jobs do you have at work?  I would like to set up the same.

How is this a discussion, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [Recommended Reports and Alerts Designs for LOGbinder for SQL Server](https://www.logbinder.com/Form/SQLReportSpecs) from Randy Smith. Although it is product specific to [LOGbinder](https://www.logbinder.com/Products/LOGbinderSQL/), you can easily translate it using the [SQL Audit Events List](http://www.logbinder.com/Products/LOGbinderSQL/EventsGenerated).

Answer (score -1):

For sql server auditing, you can checkout the following article to set up and use the feature

SQL Server Audit How-to Topics

technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280505(v=sql.105).aspx

SQL Server Audit

technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386(v=sql.110).aspx

Additionally, you can also try this automated [solution](https://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/sql-server-auditing.html) which easily accomplish this task

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks, but I didn't ask what is auditing.  I just wanted to find out what are the other companies auditing/monitoring, that's all.